# how do i apply owl carosoul on images placed on top of another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanted to apply `owl carousal` to all the images placed in `list` item i,e `li`

i want to retain the big background image as it is. on top of that i want to have `image` carousal of all `list` images.

at present carousal is not working.

**here is jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/eabangalore/s7teyzpL/26/

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

```css
  .service_img{
   width:100%;
   height:500px;
   display: block;
  }
  .service_img .small-images ul li{
   display: inline-block;
      /* position:absolute; 
       top: 33%;*/
  }

  .small-images{
   top: 25%;
   left:90px;
   opacity: 0.9;
      position: absolute;
  }

     .small-images ul li{
          padding-right: 50px;
  }

  .image-text:hover{

   }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 service_img">
    <img src="https://s9.postimg.org/w3pkeix2n/Services.jpg">
    <div class="small-images"> 
      <ul>
       <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="image-text" title="image 1"></li>
       <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="image-text" title="image 2"></li>
       <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="image-text" title="image 3"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following changes to obtain the similar result.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">          
            <div class="small-images">  
                 <ul class="owl-carousel">
                    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image-text" title="image 1"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image-text" title="image 2"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image-text" title="image 3"></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

CSS

```
.small-images{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
     display: block;
    background-image: url('https://s9.postimg.org/w3pkeix2n/Services.jpg')
}
.image-text{
    margin: 10px;
}
.owl-carousel{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

Comment: can you please make the above result with all images not one, and autoplay

Comment: You can go through this link https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html it is way too easy you just have to add options in $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({ item: 5, autoplay: true });